# How do I hook up my power supply to an outlet?

Tags: power-supply, dc, outlet

I bought a VGD-75-D524 power supply for an Arduino project (since it had a 24V, 2A option) which is what I need to power my Nema 17 stepper motor.

I'm unsure how connect this to my home's 120 V outlet. I thought it would come with a wall plug or something but I guess I need to get some jumper wires to somehow connect it.

How would you guys go about supplying power to this? Also which pins to use?

[image: My new power supply]

Comment: That power supply is designed to be installed **inside** equipment with protection against finger ingress due to the exposed live terminals. The supply should also be fused to protect against faults or short-circuits in the power supply. I think you're a bit out of your depth so you should seek help from someone knowledgeable that you can trust with your life.

Comment: I definitely am, thanks for the insight on how this is applied & security measures, I've figured out how to get it running but I'll definitely take the necessary precautions .

Comment: @Transistor are you sure this supply needs a separate fuse?

Comment: @user253751 It's a good question. The [datasheet](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vgd-75.pdf) includes the protection list. The inrush current is 30 A. Normal loaded operation about 2 A. One must both prevent nuisance fuse behavior (even if someone flips the power on and off over and over) while also making sure that the fuse blows before a fire can start. Some thought would be needed to size and then find an appropriate slow blow fuse for this. If added, the fuse may need to be placed a holder within the AC wiring itself, leading up to this unit.

Comment: @jonk I'm still not sure that implies there isn't a fuse built-in.

Comment: @user253751 The lack of any mention of fusing in the datasheet underneath the section titled *"PROTECTIONS"* is an implication. But I don't take it as proof, of course.

Answer (score 3):

AC(L) and AC(N) is where you connect the 120V house power. The connection to the right of that is ground. You can cut and strip a computer power cord.

- Black wire is AC(L) aka line
- White wire is AC(N) aka neutral
- Green wire is ground

http://www.electricalterminology.com/usa-electrical-wire-colors/

5V Vout

- +Vo1 is +5V
- -Vo1 is 0V

24 Vout

- +Vo2 is 24V
- -Vo2 is 0V

-Vo2 and -Vo1 may or may not be connected to each other, and may or may not be connected to ground.  If they are not this is called 'isolated' and the negative connection is not ground and can be attached to any voltage.
If you want to be sure they are all 'ground', aka 0V, you can attach -Vo2, -Vo1, and ground.  You probably want to do this.

I generally search for the datasheet of power supplies i use, search 'VGD-75-D524' and see what you can find

Comment: The answer should not suggest just connecting stripped bare wires to the screws. That's not very safe, might not be according to electric code either. The wires should have e.g. crimped terminals.

Comment: Agreed, crimping some fork terminals ideal. You can find them at some hardware stores.  Using stranded wire on screw terminals is prone to coming loose and/or shorting.  But to be fair we all have and in small home projects and not in permanent installations, it works.  If you don't have those connectors another technique is to strip the wire about 1/2 in, coat the wire in solder to make it a single solid wire for that 1/2in, curl the wire around the screw, and tighten.  This is not as good as fork terminals and is prone to breaking off if the wire moves allot. 120V is dangerous so be diligent

Answer (score 2):

You buy a power cord, cut the end of, crimp on some forks and wire it up on the AC pins and ground.

Or you buy [this](https://protosupplies.com/product/ac-to-spade-terminal-power-cord/).
[image: power cord with forks]

*The make sure not to touch it.*

Comment: Are the forks needed? I haven't used one of these but I was under the impression you could also put in bare wire, since the supply seems to have the flat plate which squishes the wire evenly. I suppose forks are safer in all circumstances.

Comment: @user253751 You are right that the "flat plate" (which is actually a slightly more complex shape than that) under the screw head is *designed* for bare wire ends, *properly arranged* underneath and tightened. The crimped "forks" are for cases where that isn't included. Lots of cases just have a screw and perhaps a washer. In those cases the crimped ends are necessary. Do not allow any bare wire to leave the protection zone, though. Insulation should go fully into the divided sections.

Comment: @user253751 You can use forks, ferrules or solid wire. These terminals do not take stranded.